# Rails 3 - doing more at "database level"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, optimization

I'm working on my first large Rails app and I'm a little confused about something.

I know that doing more work at database level will increase performance. But I'm confused as to what type of commands are running at the database level.

For example:

```
@tasks = @project.tasks
<%= render partial: 'task', collection: @tasks %>
```

Is that working on the database level?

Thanks, I know this is a very novice question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'doing more work at database level will increase performance'

Yes it will.  The very fundamental rails stuff i.e

@thing = Thing.find(id)

Is very efficient and you normally don't concern yourself with performance in these cases,

BUT , what about a filter of some kind.

Say you wanted to implement feature where you search for a name containing a specific set of characters,  (this is a contrived example,  just to illustrate)

You could do this:

```
@things = Thing.all
@foothings = []
@things.each do |thing|
  if /foo/ =~ thing.name
    @foothings << thing 
  end
end
```

Or you could do this:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.filtered(what)
     self.where("name like ?","%#{what}%")
   end
end


@foothings = Thing.filtered("foo")
```

The database is going to perform the search much faster (2nd example).  It's highly tuned and optimized C code (likely),  where RoR is still an interpreted language.  Also, In the first example, ALL things are requested from the database,  in the second ONLY things with 'foo' in the name are returned,  if there is network latency between the RoR machine and database machine,  that could also affect performance.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the distinction I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `@project` is a ActiveRecord object with a relationship to a Task class then a fetch is done to the database to populate the `@tasks` object.

When you run rails server watch the output of the console.  It will show you when it makes a SQL query to the database.  This will help you understand the process as your code executes.  Have fun with Rails!

Answer (score 0):

The database level isn't actually a part of your code, unless you actually write the database you are going to use. Good program design interfaces with a database, like you give mysql a query and it queries a database for your and returns the results which you use in your code. So the database level is mysql querying itself for the results, and this is where you want most of the work done because it has been highly optimized already. Where the performance comes in is dumping most of the work on it, for example you can formulate a query like: "SELECT * from mytable" and then you will get a whole bunch of elements and if thats what you want then great but if you want a specific item from this set, you'd have to use some find algorithm on the whole set (potentially having to scan them all or whatever, its bad performance) or you could query the db more specifically (SELECT * from mytable WHERE x blah) and return a smaller set of results ready to be used, and that will 99% of the time give you better performance.